# Cisco 3570x stack behaviour

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst, layer2

Could you please advise on following:

We have two Cisco 3570x switches in a stack (switches have no Stack Power).

What will be the behavior if:

1. Master switch will be powered off. Will Slave reboot by itself?
2. Slave switch will be powered off. Will it affect Master in any ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Master switch will be powered off. Will Slave reboot by itself?

When the master is powered off, the switch with the next highest priority will take over as the master switch. There is no rebooting involved.

> Slave switch will be powered off. Will it affect Master in any ways?

No. It is like a chassis switch losing a port line card. You will lose the ports of the non-master switch, but it doesn't affect anything else.

Comment: To piggy back on what @Ron Maupin said, The best way, IMHO, to view a 3X50 stack is as a chassis switch, rather than a conglomeration of individual switches.

Comment: @ZackScaringello, a chassis switch with as many redundant supervisors cards as there are port line cards.

Comment: .@RonMaupin that is an excellent point of clarification.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Stacking features  helps in increase Switchport and redandency capabilities

**Power stacking cables**

Power stacking cable connecting two switch help power redundancy between switch . If primary switch power fails ,still primary switch get power from secondary switch through power stacking cables .

**Switch stacking cables**

When both primary and secondary switches are connected with switch stacking cable ,if primary switch fails still primary switch operates with help of secondary switch

`Both switch act as single switch logically`